# How do I extend a python module to include extra functionality? (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sqlite

How would I extend the sqlite3 module so if I `import Database` I can do Database.connect() as an alias to sqlite3.connect(), but define extra non standard methods?

Comment: Why do you need that? Python is dynamic, so you can add extra functions and methods and whatnot to modules, but that does *not* mean that that is a good idea. Create your own module for that code instead.

Comment: End users are sometimes not the brightest of people, so having a module which is an alias to the built in stuff but also with all the extra functionality I require would be an ideal situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own `Database` module that has the following line at the top:

```
from sqlite import *
```

Then define methods as you like, but make sure you don't overwrite anything.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a class which wraps `sqlite3`. It takes its `.connect()` method and maybe others and exposes it to the outside, and then you add your own stuff.

Another option would be subclassing - if that works.